# Cannot bind environment variable to application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

Im working with Spring-boot and PostgreSQL and failed to bind the database password to the application.properties. I have already set the DATABASE_PASSWORD to env but its still failed to bind the properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to 
java.lang.String:

Property: spring.datasource.password
Value: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:16:28
Reason: Could not resolve placeholder 'DATABASE_PASSWORD' in value "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
```

Comment: Are you sure that you put an `system environment variable` for `DATABASE_PASSWORD` ?

Comment: thank you, i restarted it and it worked, seems like at the moment it still not received the variable until i restart it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have set your database_password to a system environment as you say, than spring should use that as [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) says -:

> > The values in application.properties are filtered through the existing Environment when they are used, so you can refer back to previously defined values (for example, from System properties).

Did you try restarting ?